# Fastest Way to Create Large Numpy Arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on creating a bunch of data (10M rows or more) and am trying to understand more deeply about the best way to work with numpy arrays as quickly as possible.

I'll have 1M rows of each class of data, which I read in from different sources (async). When I'm done reading, I want to combine them into a single numpy array. I'll know the final array is 10M (precisely).

I'm thinking I have the following paths:

1. Create a global numpy array of the entire size and copy in
2. Create a global numpy array and a numpy array for each source and concat together at the end
3. Create a null global numpy array and add each row to the global array (I think this is the slowest)

However, I'm not sure how to do #1 - [numpy.copyto](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html) seems to always start with index 0.

Is there another model. I should be going with here?

If I use "views", I'm not clear how to copy it to the final array. I'm, of course, familiar with views for DBs, but not for numpy.

Comment: There is no need to use `copyto`. You can just copy a view of an array into a view of another. Besides this, you can also append array to a list and concatenate them but the copy solution is certainly the fastest as long as you know the size of the merged array. By the way, I am not sure to understand what a "mental model" is supposed to mean (and so what is really the question).

Comment: #1 is the most efficient way, if you know the final size

Comment: "mental model" just  meant thinking about the way things are stored under the hood (e.g. how does numpy manage large in memory objects and copying). @JérômeRichard - can you say more about views and copying? I don't see how to do that with "copy". Also, is it better to provision the entire array to start, and then copy in?

Comment: Practice with smaller arrays and datasets.  At the very least this helps eliminate the bad options.  A `numpy` stores its values in one contiguous block.  For very large ones that may be broken up into 'pages' and 'caches', but that's a operating system/processor detail that you as  a Python coder don't touch.

Comment: You can just do for example something like `result[row_start:row_end,:] = some_rows[row_start2:row_end2,:]`.

Comment: Lol, that’s amazing - numpy is so powerful, just hidden. If you’d like to submit that as an answer, I’ll accept it.